How to replace pkg with latest nodeJs native alternative?
in my package.json I have
"compile": "pkg ./build/main.js --target node18 --output release/server"

it compiles js into node executable
but pkg supports only up to node18, how to use node single executable instead in my package.json?
node:latest (22 for example)

Are there any ways for cross-compilation? for example on windows for linuxstatic-x64 or linuxstatic-arm64
